# Can I use a windows 10 restore usb created on another computer?

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

If I created a windows 10 restore usb, can I use this to restore a computer other than the one I created it on or do I need the usb restore created from that specific pc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use it to restore a computer which has the same OS version, build and edition.

Comment: by build do you mean x64 architecture?

Comment: Yes those need to be of same architecture